# microphone terminal determination

Tags: microphone

Hello, I am trying to determine what the wires are for my splice microphone audio jack.
here is a picture of it split :
[image]
I did a continuity test to see which part of the jack terminal was connected to the two wires :
[image]
I am guessing the white wire is the signal wire ; thus, the bare copper wire is the gnd?
thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Yes, it should be that the ground wire is the bare one.

Answer (score 1):

The Copper wire which is bare is the Ground wire,The signal wire will be covered to suppress influence of any noise or shorting. There is a chance that the signal wire has an extra insulation on itself[usually colored], so it is advised to heat or bring the metal wire-tip into candle flame and heat it[you can see the insulation burning,if any] before any hack or soldering being done.

Comment: Or you could just strip the insulation back rather than using a candle, it seems a bit caveman to me

Comment: @Hayman this is not the usual sheathe[plastic] i'm talking about ,but a very thin insulating layer called enamel that cover the  conductors, which will be colored sometimes.The best way to remove it is by burning it.I have done it a countless number of times in headsets.

Comment: You mean enameled wire, the enamel will just melt off when you're soldering it. I thought you were referring to the dielectric insulator, my bad.